# ASP.NET vNext on Mono, install new runtime version

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, mono, asp.net-core

I trying to run asp.net vnext demo apps from here https://github.com/aspnet/Home,
ConsoleApp working fine, but HelloWeb throws System.IO.FileNotFoundException exception when I trying to launch kestrel.

I have following environment:

- OS Debian
- Mono version 3.12.0
- Vnext runtime version - 1.0.0-beta4-11169

I think problem in version mismatch. I have *runtime* version **beta4** and *project.json* file, that refers on **beta3** assemblies.

So, I need to install runtime version beta3. In general I understand that first of all I must install
runtime beta 3 version with **kvm install** command, and then switch to beta 3 with **kvm use** command.

But this is in general, can you give more detailed description of how to install
new version runtime with  examples of correct commands?

Comment: When you get a `FileNotFoundException`, it might be a good idea to post the message saying what file it was that couldn't be found.

Comment: "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.IConfiguration, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.IConfiguration, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke

Comment: As far as I'm aware ASP.NET 5 (vNext) runs on .NET Core, which itself is cross-platform. You only need full .NET if there's a framework feature you need that Core doesn't provide (which shouldn't be the case for a typical web application). That means you shouldn't need Mono, at all.

Comment: try those command : export KRE_FEED=[https://www.nuget.org/api/v2](https://www.nuget.org/api/v2) then kvm upgrade

Comment: From the aspnet github pages: "NOTE: There is no Core CLR currently available on OSX/Linux. There is only a single platform (mono45) and a single architecture (x86)."

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix versions between betas as this causes problems. Also upgrade to the latest version which is Beta 7 at the time of writing. Follow the official [announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/09/02/announcing-availability-of-asp-net-5-beta7.aspx) instructions on how to upgrade.